# How does ambient sounds work?

Tags: supertux

I'm confused. How do ambient sounds work in the SuperTux Milestone 2 level editor? I'm trying to make the sound of waves in a level with the sea in it, but no matter what I try, no sound plays. Can someone who has experience with this help me? Thanks...

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've tried changing the Volume, Distance Factor and Distance Bias values, but still nothing plays. Could it be a bug in 5.1?

Answer (score 1):

Right now it doesn't seem to work ([Github Issue](https://github.com/SuperTux/supertux/issues/806)). As an alternative you can try playing sounds with scripting, like `play_sound("sounds/door.wav");`. It’s not the same but worth having a look at. For more information to scripts see the [Scripting Reference on the old SuperTux Wiki](http://supertux.lethargik.org/wiki/Scripting_reference).

If AmbientSound works with a future SuperTux version, I will update this answer or you visit the [SuperTux Forum](https://forum.freegamedev.net/viewforum.php?f=66) with latest news and more helping people than on this Q&A.

Comment: I see. Sorry I took so long to see this. I just haven't checked Arqade in a while... Thanks!